# How to Select from 2 table in one OleDbDataAdaptercommand in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a `database` in access 2013, and I want to select from 2 of it's tabale in one command, 
this is my try:

```
OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"Select FeedName from tFeeds where FeedID IN (Select FeedID from tFeedsRations),
                                                        FeedQuantity from tFeedsRations", Connection);
        DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
        DataA.Fill(DTable);
```

but it gives:

> syntax error (comma) in query expression 'FeedID IN (Select FeedID from  tFeedsRations)

is it possible to do smoething like that at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select FeedName from tFeeds where FeedID IN (Select FeedID from tFeedsRations), FeedQuantity from tFeedsRations`is not valid SQL.

It looks like you're trying to perform a join, which would be does as follows.

`SELECT tf.FeedName, tfr.FeedQuanity
 FROM tFeeds AS tf 
 INNER JOIN tFeedsRations AS tfr ON (tf.FeedID = tfr.FeedID)`